# Finding corresponding code segment from UI-Element Winforms

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I recently started working on a rather large project with a lot of UI elements in the code. Is there a quick way to go from the UI Element, when I run the application, to the corresponding element in the Code?
I feel like there must be a way, because the application has incredibly many files and ressources and I can't figure out how to find the Element.

Comment: What is the *the corresponding element in the Code*? The Field that declares the Control object? Any code you may have anywhere that references that Control? All event handlers you may have subscribed to? -- What would *find the Element* mean? -- If you want to find all references of a Control, find the instance in the `.Designer.cs` file and press `SHIFT+F12`, selecting `Entire Solution` as the scope of the search.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the problem is that I'm looking for the ".Designer.cs" file in the Project. Is there a way to find this file from the UI Element when I start the application?